# Stack Overflow Books

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Stack Overflow is where bright minds meet. I wish this site publish a book containing questions and answers of different users.

Answers given by the programmers who use Stack Overflow amaze us for many reaosns: their great ideas, solid analysis and accurate answers; much of which is usually not found in other books or tutorials.

You gave so many different possible correct solutions that the phrase, "there are many ways to kill the chicken," comes to mind.

Publishing a book such as this would benefit students, beginners, intermediate and master programmers alike.

Agree or disagree? Possible or impossible?

Comment: But how many ways *can* you kill a chicken?

Comment: http://www.myvideo.de/watch/3265991/

Answer (score 5):

It may actually be a good idea. I believe there have been precedents when some sites published the best of their online contributions.

On the other hand it promotes the idea of collaborative editing. Meaning, the most up-to-date version is only online.

Comment: It'd be a snapshot in time -- for both good and ill. The best-qualified questions for a book such as that have to be timeless, which means they'd likely have to come from the pool of community wiki "fun" questions. Not seeing it. (no downvote, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, the best answer I come across, I tend to put in my personal wiki with a link to the question and proper attribution.
This allow me to have a copy of all the knowledge I think is valuable, while keeping the ability to go back to it at any time.

A book sounds interesting. Although, you'd have to have Jon Skeet Facts in there somewhere. :)